# Paste in Nano is not working

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, terminal, nano

I used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> to select a block of text in Nano, then cut it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>. 
This successfully removed the text from my buffer.

But when I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to paste what I had cut, nothing is pasted.

Where did my text go? Can I get it back?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! `Ctrk+K` / `Ctrl+U` is the usual yank/paste sequence, so if that didn't do what you were expecting I can understand your confusion and question!

Comment: Check that the version of nano is recent. It looks like 2.0.6 is current.

Comment: Just tried it with my nano (GNU nano 4.9, built for cygwin): After Ctrl-Shift-6, I need to move the cursor with the shift key pressed down, in order to select the block, otherwise nothing will be copied. Did you use the shift key? What happens if you select the area with the mouse? Please also state your OS and your nano-version.

Answer (score 0):

`M-A (^6)` or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>) Marks text starting from the cursor position

`M-6 (M-^)` or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>) Copies current line (or marked region) and stores it in the cutbuffer.

Answer (score 0):

To cut and paste text in `nano`, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> in sequence.

To paste from clipboard into `nano`, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> does the tricky.